# Graph Theory—Number of ways to color the graph $C_4$ with $r$ colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

> **Question**: How many ways can you *properly* color the cycle *C*$_{4}$ with
>   *r* colors? And in general, how many ways are there to properly color the cycle *C*$_{n}$ with *r* colors?

[image]

**Thought process:**

- If I begin at the top left vertex, I have a choice of *r* colors.
- Then, if I move to the top right vertex, I have $r$ — 1 options to choose from.
- If I next move to the bottom right vertex, I can't use the same color I used on the top right vertex or the top left **(since I have to use all $r$ colors—or do I?**), so I would have $r-2$ choices.
- For the bottom left vertex, with similar reasoning as the previous step, I would have $r — 3$ choices.
- Finally, to determine the total number of ways to color $C_{4}$ with $r$ colors, I multiply each of these numbers together, giving
  $(r)(r — 1)(r — 2)(r — 3)$

So, am I spouting total nonsense or am I on to something? For $C_{4}$ does $r$ have to be at least a certain number? Whatever the right answer is, I'm assuming finding the number of ways to color $C_{n}$ with $r$ colors is similar?

Comment: If you had to use all $r$ colors the answer would be $0$ for all $r\gt4$.

Comment: No, you have not to use all $r$ colors. Just count the colorings with at most $r$ colors such that any adjacent vertices have different color.

Answer (score 3):

For $r=2$ we have $2$ proper colorings, i.e. $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ can be $(c_1,c_2,c_1,c_2)$ or $(c_2,c_1,c_2,c_1)$ but according to your formula $(r)(r — 1)(r — 2)(r — 3)$ we find $0$ colorings. So it is not correct.

In order to find $c_4(r)$ i.e. the number of proper colorings of $C_4$ with $r$ colors, we consider two distinct cases.

1) **Vertex 1 and vertex 3 have the same color**: we choose such color in $r$ ways and we have $(r-1)$ choices for vertex 2 and $(r-1)$ choices for vertex 4. Thus we obtain
$$r\cdot (r-1)^2.$$

2) **Vertex 1 and vertex 3 have two different colors**: we choose such colors in $r(r-1)$ ways and we have $(r-2)$ choices for vertex 2 and $(r-2)$ choices for vertex 4. Thus we obtain: 
$$r\cdot (r-1)\cdot (r-2)^2$$

Hence the total number is
$$c_4(r)=r\cdot (r-1)^2+r\cdot (r-1)\cdot (r-2)^2=r(r-1)(r^2-3r+3).$$

Can you extend this approach and find $c_5(r)$?

What about the number $c_n(r)$ of proper colorings  of $C_n$ with $r$ colors?

P.S. For the general case, not that the formulas 1) and 2) can be read as $c_{2}(r)\cdot (r-1)$ and $c_{3}(r)\cdot (r-2)$, respectively.

Comment: No. In case 1 we choose the SAME color for vertex 1 and 3.

Comment: For Case 1, the r for vertices 1 & 3 isn't squared? i.e. we don't have (r^2)(r - 1)^2 ?

Comment: No, we have $r$ choices for the SAME color for vertex 1 and 3. If we have red and blue, then we have 2 choices and not $2^2$: (red,red) or (blue,blue).

Comment: @wannabemathmajor Before the general case, can you find the number of proper colorings of $C_5$?